# Error of bounded mean estimation with quantization

Tags: self-study, estimation, error, mean

I have a distribution whose mean $\theta \in [0,1]$. Given $n$ observations, I compute the sample mean (say $\hat{\theta}$) and quantize it to accuracy $\frac{1}{n}$ (basically I can use only $\log{n}$ bits to communicate this sample mean). Let us call the quantized version of $\hat{\theta}$ as $\hat{\theta}_q$. I want to upper bound $\mathbb{E}[(\hat{\theta}_q - \theta)^2]$. I am supposed to get that it is upper bounded by $\frac{2}{n}$. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

This is what I tried. Let $\mu_{ML}$ denote the sample mean. We know that $\hat{\theta}_q \in [\mu_{ML} - \frac{1}{n}, \mu_{ML} + \frac{1}{n}]$. We have that:

\begin{align}
\mathbb{E}[(\hat{\theta}_q - \theta)^2] &= \mathbb{E}[\hat{\theta}_q^2] + \theta^2 - 2\theta\mathbb{E}[\hat{\theta}_q] \nonumber \\
&\le \mathbb{E}[\hat{\theta}_q^2] + \theta^2 - 2\theta \mathbb{E}\left[\mu_{ML} - \frac{1}{n}\right] \nonumber \\
&= \mathbb{E}[\hat{\theta}_q^2] - \theta^2 + \frac{2\theta}{n}
\end{align}

I know that $\theta$ is upper bounded by 1, but I don't know how to get rid of the $\mathbb{E}[\hat{\theta}_q^2] - \theta^2$ part.

EDIT:
[This is not a HW question. I read in a footnote in this paper - http://www.cs.berkeley.edu/~yuczhang/files/nips13_communication.pdf (bottom of Page 3) and I want to understand it]

Comment: @Glen_b: Thanks for the note. I have edited the original post.